# How do find out the last time database is updated in laravel 5?

Tags: php, mysql, database, laravel-5

I need to display information on when is the last time the database records has been changed, the timestamp of last (delete, update, insert) operation. Help needed , much appreciated.

Comment: this is database stuff, you have to maintain history to display that database record has been changed. Every time you have to add/edit the timestamp whatever the operation happens.

Comment: every field in the table have a default updated_at field inserted by laravel everytime i update something, however the problem is i have many tables. How do i retrieve the "last updated timestamp" among all tables and columns?

Comment: the simplest solution for me is that make one function which updates the timestamp everytime when any action takes place in db. make one table with timestamp and update that field...